# avaje.org/ very often down

Tags: ebean

I started using Ebean and I like it. But for the beginning I need access to documentation and stuff like that. Now I wanted to download the source of Ebean to integrate it in Eclipse. But the website http://www.avaje.org/ is down, AGAIN.

I working with Ebean since three days and for the hole time the website is very slow or not even reachable. Is this normal? Can I trust a project which project website is not reachable? I want to use it for at least (!) one or two years - but at the moment I do not trust that project. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of Ebean as well and have been using it for about 9 months now and have found it very reliable. This is the first time I've seen the site down since I've been using it, so it is a bit of a surprise. However if it makes you feel any better, it is the default ORM included for the Java portion of Play Framework 2.0 ( http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaEbean ), if that speaks for its reliability.

Also I would try posting to EBeans google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/ebean (it's still quite active) if you're worried. Rob Bygrave the primary maintainer just answered a post about a week ago. He did also mention that his EBean involvement is on hold until after February of this year due to scheduling.

Edit: sources are also available by maven repo:
http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.avaje%22%20AND%20a%3A%22ebean%22

Comment: Sure thing I should also note you can get the sources from a Maven repo like: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.avaje%22%20AND%20a%3A%22ebean%22

Comment: I've also noticed that the avaje.org website is down very often, which is unfortunate because then you can't view the official Ebean documentation when you need help.